# Deploying AngularJS app to Azure via github not working

Tags: node.js, azure, gruntjs, azure-web-app-service

Long story short, we have an old, ill-maintained web app hosted in a google cloud account we don't have access to anymore, so we want to move it over to our company Azure account.

In Azure, we created a new web app, and set it to pull from our repo.  First build failed, but that's because it was using a really old Kudu deployment script.  So I generated a new one (using azure-cli) and pushed the new script.  In Azure, the build succeeded now, but when I go to the url for the site, nothing is there.  As far as I can tell, the app is never starting.

[Here's all of the information that I could think of that might be relevant.](https://gist.github.com/Keirathi/f0a194ac2eb8da1c2d85b4a122041174) I don't fully understand all of the gruntfile stuff (I just know I type 'grunt serve' to work on the app locally :P), so I'm not sure if that's what I'm missing or what.  If there's any other info needed, just let me know and I can add it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do mean by "not working"? Are you running into **404** or **500** error?

Comment: Did you check the status in Azure portal? any screenshot would be helpful. pls share.

Comment: Sorry, I had to sleep.

@AaronChen-MSFT Sorry I wasn't specific.  Getting '403 (Forbidden)'.

Comment: @ArunVinoth Screenshots of what, exactly?  IE, in the web servce tab, if you tell me what you want to see exactly, I can get it.

Comment: So, I've done some more digging in Azure using the Kudu Advanced Tools.  In '/wwwroot', my app resides in a subdirectory there called 'app'.  index.html is in the app subdirectory.  If I manually type in %our azure url%/app/index.html, it does try to load the html file, but everything is broken because all of the script/styles/etc path structures are broken.  IE, it's trying to load them from /wwwroot/scripts/app.js, /wwwroot/styles/main.css  instead of from /wwwroot/app/.  It seems it's not respecting the appPath variable set in the gruntfile?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using [`HTML <base> element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) to specify the base URL for all relative URLs contained within a document.

In this case, you can specify a base URL in `index.html` like below:

```
<head>
    <base href="/app/">
</head>
```

Also, if you don't want type `/app/index.html` in the URL to visit your site, you cloud add this to **Default documents** under **Application settings** menu in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

[image]